# Only change one property of ReplaySubject

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a ReplaySubject of type `UserDetails`.

```
userData: ReplaySubject<UserDetails>;
```

This class has the following properties with two being optional:

```
export class UserDetails {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  shipping?: Address[];
  billing?: Address[];
}
```

To detect changes in other components via subscription, so far I've always used `this.user.next(value)` - but how do I e.g. solely change the property `shipping` of the object user?

Comment: What do you mean by solely changing the property `shipping`? Do you want to assign a new value to `shipping` and let all the others remain as is?

Comment: @31piy Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

use `distinctUntilKeyChanged` to pick up the change in shipping, but make sure you emitting shipping as new array

```
// to emit
userData.next({ ...yourOriginalObject, shipping:[1,3....]})
// subcribe to shipping change
userData.pipe(distinctUntilKeyChanged('shipping'))
```

Comment: maybe you have to change the order of `shipping` and `yourOriginalObject`

Comment: But how do I insert my original object, if my original object is the ReplaySubject. Or do I get something wrong here?

Comment: um.. that depends on your code context and the reason u use relaySubject. Although you can get the lastest relaysubject  value by relaySubject.pipe(last(),tap(originalObject=>....)) and use that to emit new value.